# Change /dev/video0 to a jpeg using v4l2loopback

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm very new to linux but learning!

I'm trying to change the camera source to a still image using v4l2loopback and ffmpeg.

Everything seems to be going to plan, except for the last step.

I have entered the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -re -I eddy.jpeg /dev/video0
```

However it says that it's unable to find a suitable output format for /dev/video0

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do, but one thing that might be tripping you up is permissions on /dev/video0 if your user isn't root.  The rest may be out of my depth.

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i input.jpg -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

- `-re` - Process input at real-time, otherwise it will go as fast as possible.
- `-loop 1` - Continuously loop the input.
- `-i input.jpg` - The input file. Note that the option is `-i`, not `-I` which is invalid (`Unrecognized option 'I'`).
- `-vf format=yuv420p` - Use [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to output a pixel format that is compatible with V4L2.
- `-f v4l2` - Manually set which output format to use. Usually this isn't needed for local, normal file outputs. But it is needed for streaming, and outputting to V4L2 can be considered a type of streaming.
- `/dev/video0` - The output.

See [Is there any way ffmpeg send video to `/dev/video0`?](https://askubuntu.com/a/881341) for more info and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Much help! However I'm now getting an error saying that I'm trying to apply and input option to an output file or vice versa. Do you know what that could be?

Comment: @Chris Need to see your command, and the complete log output if you can too.

Comment: FYI for others: If the output is fuzzy, say, because you changed the .jpg being rendered, delete the video0 device and re-create it: `./v4l2loopback-ctl delete /dev/video9; ./v4l2loopback-ctl add /dev/video9`

Comment: Seens fuzzy image not solve on Ubuntu Jammy.